# How to export data in a firebase to a csv file which already created (override) in a google drive

Tags: firebase, flutter, cloud, google-colaboratory

I am a final year undergraduate student.In my final year research project I am developing a mobile application which can predict our future personal expenses.
First I give the list of tasks with the costs which have spent to particular task.As a example Imagine I want to buy some apple.So I add that task to the app like todo application.Once I finished that task I will add the cost which has spent for buy apple.These data are stored in the google Firebase.
I have a separate ML model which can predict the future expense like how much money will i want in next month for food etc.That ML model's data set is stored in the google drive as a CSV file.That CSV file have not connection with the data that are stored in the Firebase.So
I need to export the data that in the Firebase to csv file which I already created in the google drive.How can I do this.
I also need a proper way to fetch data from model to my mobile application.

technologies that I have used so far are Firebase,Flutter,google colabs

Comment: Which database are you using real-time or firestore in firebase?

Comment: I am using firestore

Comment: You would first set up a Firestore project. Then, after reviewing the [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) documentation, would write some code that reads the data in your Firestore and then writes it out as a .csv file. Along the way, after you've attempted some code, when you get stuck, you would post the code here and describe the problem. Then we would be able to help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.